# Shell script to execute grep with time and provide the output in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to write a script which will execute the command

`cat file.txt | grep -c 'HH:MM'` [here HH:MM will be from 00:00 to 23:59]
and what ever the output is would like to save in a file in a format
00:00 - 2134
00:01 - 3127
.
.
.
.
23:59 - 1298

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Something like `grep -Eo "[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" | sort | uniq -c` ?

Comment: there is a file in my server, where request comes from mobile device and count is huge(like more than 100 request per min). I want to get the count of request so that i can calculate at which time the request is high. So when i execute `cat file.txt | grep -c '10:30'` it will give count of message in 10:30. Similarly will get for 00:00, 00:01, 00:02 ..... ..... ...23:59.

Comment: the message which flow consists of IP, description and time as well. That's why  I want to filter out with time. And want to store all the count in a separate file created by script with respect to time. For example 00:00 - count a, 00:01 - count b, like this. Hope this explanation have some clear view

Comment: i got the solution. Thanks @WalterA . Your command line worked after some modification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the extra command `cat` when you add the filename in the grep command.
When access.log is already sorted on the date, you can skip the sorting.

```
grep -Eo "2017-04-25T[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" /local/logs/access.log | uniq -c > /tmp/list.txt
```

With access.log you must be aware that somebody can "attack" your scripts (make the statistics fail) by tryint to acces the webpage http://yoursite/2017-04-25T11:11/fooledyou.html
You can use `sed` for more control how you select substrings

```
# test remove from start of line until the first [ and also remove the [,
# remember the matched date and remove the rest, replace by remembered string.
echo "127.0.0.1 - - [2017-04-25T11:11 +0000] GET /2017-04-25T22:22/fooledyou.html HTTP/1.1 200 140 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.5 Safari/535.19" |
   sed 's/[^\[]*\[\(2017-04-25T[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\).*/\1/'

# your command
sed 's/[^\[]*\[\(2017-04-25T[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\).*/\1/' /local/logs/access.log |
   uniq -c > /tmp/list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

script is of one line.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /local/logs/access.log | grep -Eo "2017-04-25T[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" | sort | uniq -c > /tmp/list.txt
```

After executing I got a file list.txt and when I open it, get the list as mentioned below.

[Output of the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk9ag.png)